# Auto updating items in a database as active/inactive in Powerapps

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a form in PowerApps which will add new assets into a table in Microsoft SQL.

Currently you can add the info shown in the snippet below [image]

When you select the + button it adds that info into the table but I'm currently at a pause on how to get it to auto update an asset as we add more in (for the purpose of history tracking).

For example we have a service tag of abcd1234 which has been assigned to Jack white the laptop is active. A year later jack leaves the company and we now assign the laptop abcd1234 to Mary Jones so now the laptop is active for the user Mary Jones but inactive for Jack White. As time goes by the most recent user assigned to that laptop will be active whilst previous users will be shown as inactive.

The purpose of this is so users who search for a laptop will be shown the most current user and they have the option to select that asset and view their history.

I have included the table below where IsActive will be 1 for active and 0 for inactive.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm skeptical that all your columns are likely to have more than 8,000 characters in them. What Device Makers/Models have names that long?

Comment: It was used as a test for a different issue that I was having.

Comment: What is your question here? You don't ask anything.

Comment: how can I get my table to automatically update an asset as INACTIVE through powerapps when I add a new asset with the same service tag so I can keep track of which is the most current user of that device so when a user searches for that asset it only shows the recent user instead of every user who has owned that device.

Comment: Have you application do an `UPDATE` first and the `INSERT` the new row. Or, if it's calling a procedure, that should do an `UPDATE` and then an `INSERT`. Just make sure this is all done within a transaction.

Comment: You can't get your app to automatically update it, you need to write the specific code.
If I recall correctly you need to PATCH (update) the record to inactive then POST a new record. Stored Procs are stupidly difficult to call in PowerApps. It's crazy, you need to use Power Automate and sometimes write a whole load of boilerplate error handing code

Comment: Yeah I know I had the choice between using patch or writing a stored procedure, someone had a stored procedure written but we debated whether it was worth putting it in. Never really used power apps before so my understanding of it is at a minimum..